# Logic App to Logic App error: AuthorizationFailed

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app 'A' that makes a call to logic app 'B' using the HTTP action. Logic app 'B' has a the "When a HTTP request is received" trigger. Under "Access control configuration" > "Trigger access option", I have it set to "Only other Logic Apps". When I run logic app 'A' and it tries to call logic app 'B', I get an error

"code": "AuthorizationFailed", "message": "The client IP address '' is not in the allowed caller IP address ranges specified in the workflow access control configuration."

Am I missing a configuration somewhere? How can I setup logic app B so that it accepts requests from logic app A? Thanks.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/restrict-logic-app-consumption-to-be-invoked-only-by-specific/ba-p/3774454

Does that help?

Comment: Yup that's perfect. Looks like I need to use the logic apps child action instead of the HTTP action when calling the child logic app with it set to "Only other logic apps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `HTTP` trigger in the parent logic app to trigger a child logic app, you need to make the below changes in **Workflow settings -> Access control configuration**.

[image]

You need to select **Specific IP ranges** in **Trigger access option** only if you are directly invoking the child logic app URL in parent logic app or calling it from postman.

You can refer to the [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/restrict-logic-app-consumption-to-be-invoked-only-by-specific/ba-p/3774454) shared by **@Skin** in the comment.
But to use any other trigger like **When a HTTP request is received** apart from **HTTP** and invoking the child logic app using **Azure Logic apps** connector in the parent logic app, you need to set the **`Trigger access option to Only other logic app`** in Access control configuration.

Here I am using **HTTP** trigger in parent logic app and **When a HTTP request is received** in child logic app. I have added the **IP ranges for triggers** field in Access control configuration of child logic app.

Upon triggering the parent logic app, I am getting 202 Accepted response in **Overview -> Trigger history** of parent's logic app.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I need to switch to using the logic apps child action instead of the HTTP action when I have it set to "Only other logic apps".